# Why does this Java code throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why does the following Java code throw a NullPointerException?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getInteger(null);
}

public static Integer getInteger(Number n) {
    return (n == null || n instanceof Integer) ? (Integer)n : n.intValue();
}
```

EDIT: I added parentheses to end the confusion about "whether I am sometimes returning a boolean".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's what I thought too. Test it yourself :)

Comment: as a sidenode, `n instanceof Integer` will also fail if `n` is null, so you are basicly checking it twice.

Comment: if LHS condition made true then how RHS side goes compiter , if i am not wrong then LHS return true then it won't go to RHS, Question is very good, i appreciate, but i am looking that many answer came and also get upvote , but no body explaining my this query. can any one please and make me correct

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope. Try the code with parentheses. Still throws NullPointerException.

Comment: @HansBrende change `n.intValue()` to `Integer.valueOf(n.intValue())` (all the current answers seem incorrect).

Comment: @assylias thank you for the only correct response! Java auto-unboxing at work... shoulda known.

Comment: @assylias Can you explain what is actually happening?  In the case of a `null` input, what is the boxed type of `n` that is throwing an exception with the case `(Integer)n`?  This is not clear to me.  Please post an answer.

Comment: @Tim, since the second part of the expression is `n.intValue()` which gives an **primitive int**, the compiler uses unboxing on the first part as well... So `(Integer) n` becomes `((Integer) n).intValue()` in compiled code. So this throws a NPE on null input. Hope it clears.

Answer (score 4):

Credit is completely due to @assylias who discovered the answer.  Use this code instead:

```
public static Integer getInteger(Number n) {
    return (n == null || n instanceof Integer) ? (Integer)n : Integer.valueOf(n.intValue());
}
```

Because of weird boxing/unboxing rules, since `n.intValue()` returns a primitive `int`, the compiler was unboxing `n` in the expression `(Integer)n` to a primitive as well.  <strike>And `null` cannot be assigned to a primitive (just try doing that in your IDE).</strike>

### Edit:

The NPE is not really because `null` is being assigned to a primitive (the compiler would not do that), but it's because **unboxing** is done by calling `Integer.intValue()` method and the method is called on a `null` reference in this case.

Comment: But this doesn't tell me why my code failed.

Comment: Yes it does.  In the case of `null`, you were trying to return a `boolean` value in the RHS expression.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen don't you think that IDE should alert the user that this statement might return boolean? I tried the code and I was thinking that..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Very good question.

Comment: Yes... It should ve been a compiler error if he is returning a boolean value instead of Integer... The catch is somewhere else.

Comment: if LHS condition made true then how RHS side goes compiter , if i am not wrong then LHS return true then it won't go to RHS

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited my question to add parentheses to remove the confusion about returning a boolean.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but `n instanceof Integer` has an inbuild `null` check and does both, check for class and check if it´s not equal to null. The Exception actually happens at `(Integer)n`, just in combination with the ternary operator.

Comment: @assylias I see it now.  But if both conditions are being boxed into `Integer`, why would there be a problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the problem is that both are being UNboxed to int.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen looks like someone edited your answer incorrectly :/

Answer (score 0):

Because here:

```
return n == null || n instanceof Integer ? (Integer)n : n.intValue();
                                             here
```

You are trying to convert the **n** (which is null) to Integer.

Comment: But null CAN be converted to an Integer.

Comment: I tried the code, the check is false so the code is not going there,

Comment: @KostasC all know because of casing time throw NullPointerException, but see n== null returns true then how moves to right side of short-circulate OR operator

Comment: while using || left side return true then it want more to right side

Comment: if LHS condition made true then how RHS side goes compiter , if i am not wrong then LHS return true then it won't go to RHS

Comment: This answer is incorrect... See duplicate.

Comment: @assylias Thanks for correcting us.